# Reputable Solidity utils library for arrays

Tags: solidity, library, tools

Is there an audited and reputable smart contracts utils library with helpers for dealing with arrays?

I haven't found anything great on Google so far.

Answer (score 2):

[Modular Network Ethereum Libraries from Github](https://github.com/Modular-Network/ethereum-libraries/tree/master/ArrayUtilsLib) is an excellent place to start although I am not sure of the audit status at this time.